# Autorefresh dashboard from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dashboard

I am trying to do some kind of visualization on C# where I have incoming data stored by another process into a SQL Server database, and my goal is to have a Windows form to display it closest to real time as possible. what is the best way to achieve this?

I thought about using a service broker but I'm not sure if that would be the best solution. I have little experience with it but I have used it before.

The inserts later on can become pretty intense, at the moment it's about 3 rows per minute, but it can get to 800 or so.

The bigger picture is that the table where I need to gather the data from is like an historical of the information to display, and the dashboard should only refresh to the latest "state" of course my table has a datetime column and an identifier to be able to pass that into the dashboard.

Example:

Table A:

```
Name: | datetime | value |
 ---
tank1 | 2016-08-11 12:10:03 | 80
tank2 | 2016-08-11 12:10:03 | 79
tank1 | 2016-08-11 12:08:03 | 90
tank2 | 2016-08-11 12:08:03 | 89
```

At this point the dashboard should read 80 at tank 1 and 79 on tank2, since its the latest reading. but the next moment data is inserted my dashboard should try to refresh, or is it too much? should i just have a periodic refresh every x seconds?

Comment: If retrieving all the data is too intensive, you may think of using a trigger and only updating those rows in the UI (if displayed at the moment).

Comment: @Andrew i just edited the post to better explain myself, had things to vague.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, than [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) should be appropriate for this job. It allows you to build real time web applications using C#.

Also [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-real-time-signalr-dashboard-angularjs/) may give you a little help with your task